# The Apache James Server App service was launched, but failed to start

Tags: apache

I am configuring the Apache james Server, But fail to start the server.
please help.Thanks in Advance.

Followed Steps:
C:\xampp\htdocs\apache-james-3.0-beta4\bin>j
wrapper  | Apache James Server App installed

C:\xampp\htdocs\apache-james-3.0-beta4\bin>j
wrapper  | Starting the Apache James Server
wrapper  | Waiting to start...
wrapper  | The Apache James Server App servi
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\xampp\htdocs\apache-james-3.0-beta4\bin>

james-server.log

INFO  12:12:51,775 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@2ba11895: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:12:51 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  12:13:12,034 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@5a8d9005: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:13:12 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  12:14:16,123 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@2ba11895: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:14:16 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  12:17:01,778 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@356cdec9: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:17:01 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  12:19:37,360 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@2ba11895: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:19:37 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  12:25:51,556 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@17c68925: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:25:51 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  12:26:17,151 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@17c68925: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:26:17 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  12:26:33,036 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@17c68925: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:26:33 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  12:30:06,836 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@2ba11895: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:30:06 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  12:32:47,145 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@356cdec9: startup date [Sat Apr 23 12:32:47 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy